# Hold the value of a variable

Tags: hold

This is my code

```
xyzzy = 1;
Hold[xyzzy] // ToString // StringLength
```

The output is 11.

This 2nd one below.

```
ClearAll[xyzzy]
 ToString[xyzzy] // StringLength]
```

The output is 5.

Why is this?

I think these 2 codes will be the same output

Comment: the result of `Hold[xyzzy]` is `Hold[xyzzy]` and that is 11 characters long. When `xyzzy` has not been assigned any value then the `ToString[xyzzy]` will be the string `xyzzy` and that is 5 characters long.

Comment: @Bill How can I fix this? How can make it have  the same output?

Comment: What output is the desired? `5`, `11`, or `1`?

Comment: Possibly `HoldForm[xyzzy] // ToString // StringLength` does what you want?

Comment: `Hold[xyzzy] // ToString // StringLength[#] - 6 &`?

Comment: or `Hold[xyzzy] // 
 ReplaceAll[ Hold[a_] :> StringLength@ ToString[Unevaluated@a]]`?

Comment: @xzczd 5 is the desired output

Comment: @Bill ```Hold[xyzzy] and that is 11 characters long.``` How can you draw such a conclusion?

Comment: To be precise, the result of `Hold[xyzzy] // ToString` is `"Hold[xyzzy]"`, and it's obviously 11 characters long.

Comment: @xzczd `'Hold[]'` in `"Hold[xyzzy]"` is counted?

Comment: Of course, it's inside the `""`.

Answer (score 2):

Your first code acts as below line:

`StringLength["Hold[xyzzy]"]`

And second one acts as below line:

`StringLength["xyzzy"]`